# deleting rows by default value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have found code that i am interested in, on this forum.
But it's not working for my dataframe.

INPUT:

```
x , y ,value ,value2
1.0 , 1.0 , 12.33 , 1.23367543
2.0 , 2.0 , 11.5 , 1.1523123
4.0, 2.0 , 22.11 , 2.2112312
5.0, 5.0 , 78.13 , 7.8131239
6.0, 6.0 , 33.68 , 3.3681231
```

i need delete rows in distance between =1, and leave only one where is highest "value"

RESULT to get:

```
1.0 , 1.0 , 12.23 , 1.23367543
4.0, 2.0 , 22.11 , 2.2112312
5.0, 5.0 , 78.13 , 7.8131239
```

CODE:

```
def dist_value_comp(row):                         
    x_dist = abs(df['y'] - row['y']) <= 1
    y_dist = abs(df['x'] - row['x']) <= 1
    xy_dist = x_dist & y_dist
    max_value = df.loc[xy_dist, 'value2'].max()
    return row['value2'] == max_value

df['keep_row'] = df.apply(dist_value_comp, axis=1)
df.loc[df['keep_row'], ['x', 'y','value', 'value2']]
```

PROBLEM:

When i am adding 4th column`value2`  where  valueshave more numbers after dot, code showing me only row with the highest `value2` but result should be same as for `value`.

UPDATE:
it's working when i am using old pycharm and python 2.7 , on new version it's not, any idea why?

Comment: What is your definition of distance? It does not look like Euclidean distance to me.

Comment: `return float(row['value']) == float(max_value)` doesn't help?

Comment: @DYZ Hello , distance is sum between two dimensions x and y in 2D position. Please tak a look on update, code doesnt work when value have more than couple places after dot, why?

Comment: @Pythonist hello, please take a look on my edited question